# trigger error to update a column with the sum of 2 other column

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, eventtrigger

I have a simple table called 'followers':

```
id fb tw sum 
1   2  4  
2   6  5
3   4  8
```

I want to create a trigger such that after inserting data into the 'fb' and 'tw' columns, the fourth colum 'sum' will be the sum of fb+tw.

Here is my code for the trigger:

```
USE `my_database`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `followers_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `followers` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
UPDATE sum SET sum=fb+tw
END
DELIMITER;
```

I keep getting a DDL error.

Comment: Don't perform an UPDATE of the row from inside the trigger. To achieve the specified goal, use a **`BEFORE INSERT`** trigger to assign the value of an expression to the column. Values assigned to the columns can be referenced (within the trigger) by prefixing the column references **`NEW.`**.  The body of your trigger would be something like: **`SET NEW.sum = NEW.fb + NEW.tw ;`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `before` trigger. And set the values with the `NEW` keyword to indicate the currently inserted record

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `followers_AINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `followers` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  SET NEW.sum = NEW.fb + NEW.tw;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Also use a space between `delimiter` and the actual delimiter to change the definition.

Comment: This works but i am a little confused..If i want to update the sum column after inserting values into fb and tw columns, why am i using BEFORE INSERT? Thanks

Comment: Because you can't change the values AFTER the insert is done. You have to modify them BEFORE they are inserted

Comment: So the column we are referencing when we say BEFORE INSERT ON or AFTER INSERT ON is the 'sum' column and not the other 2 col?

Comment: You can define 2 kinds of triggers. The ones that are fired right before the actual insert is happening. In there you can adjust all the column values before the actual insert is done. After the insert you can fire the AFTER triggers to do other stuff. But you can access all column values in both triggers. But there AFTER triggers don't allow changes to the column values since they are alredy inserted