# mysql trigger to update column y as sum of a and b when a and b is updated in PHP mySQl

Tags: mysql, eventtrigger

The fact is I built an app with grid having three columns, a,b and y. y is the sum of a and b
but the user can only edit a or b at a time. this is my code: this one updates a or b. i know I can easily select the value of a and b from the database and write another query to update 'y' but to use the mysql trigger function will be great

```
if ( $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE ".$tablename." SET ".$colname." = ? WHERE id = ?")) {
$stmt->bind_param("si",$value, $id);
$return = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

the question is somehow related to this, but i need it in PHP

[trigger error to update a column with the sum of 2 other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126748/trigger-error-to-update-a-column-with-the-sum-of-2-other-column)

Comment: What do you mean by "I need it in PHP" ? A trigger as a procedure in the database and independent of the language which you use to access the database. Did you try to define a trigger? How?

Comment: based on your comment, I do not need it in PHP again, how do i create the trigger in MYSql database?

Comment: RTFM. Or try Google. Or see here: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx. Or elsewhere.